# Git push to Git server and Github at the same time with a single command?

Tags: git, githooks, git-config

I have a self hosted git server on a virtual private server and i am trying to push to that server and to git hub at the same time, i don't know if i can do it by adding remote accounts to the client git config or if i would be able to do so with a git hook on the server repository, I am feeling a little out of my depth here.

Comment: If you use Unix shell and not some graphical UI you can always chain two commands with `&&`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+push+multiple+remotes